# Animating radius growth/shrink of a circle on google maps in a given time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, geometry

I´m trying to animate the growth/shrink of the radius of a circle on the Google Maps API. Right now what I have is a method in JS that takes the time given, the final radius and calculates a delta of the radius, with that it calculates the time rate (or the number of milliseconds to wait until the next iteration of the cycle). The thing is that it's working for larger times (like 3 seconds or more) and for smaller times it's taking it more than it should (almost for everything lower or equal to 1 sec, it's taking it like 2 secs).
Here's the method>

```
var animateRadius = function(change){
        var radiusDelta = Math.abs(change.FinalRadius-Circle.getRadius());
        var radiusChangeRate = 1;
        var timeRate = (radiusChangeRate*change.FinalTime)/radiusDelta;
        if(timeRate <= 1){
            /*since the setInterval method only works with miliseconds
              if the timespan is less than one milisecond, the radius change 
              rate has to be bigger in order to make it on time, and since this
              only happens in smaller times, I think the error is around here..*/ 
            timeRate = 1;
            radiusChangeRate = (timeRate*radiusDelta)/change.FinalTime; 
                        }
        if(change.FinalRadius > Circle.getRadius()){
            //This just tells if the circle is growing or shrinking
            radiusChangeRate = radiusChangeRate*-1; 
        }

        var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
            if(visionRadiusCircle.getRadius() == change.FinalRadius){
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                interval = 0;
            }
            Circle.setRadius(Circle.getRadius() - radiusChangeRate);

        }, timeRate);
    }
```

I can't figure out why this is not working. Any thoughts? Any idea is welcome, even if it's a different algorithm (I'm not even sure if there's a better way to do this).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe make the delta time constant at something like 0.1 sec; then change the the delta radius to match (realistically, you probably don't get enough of the processor to do anything much faster than that, certainly not every millisecond).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, what is weird is that, for example for 1 sec, it takes the program near 3 seconds to finish, but for 10 seconds it takes it like 10.57 secs to do it. Something is messing up with smaller times.

Comment: What is are the values of radiusDelta and timeRate when it is configured for 1 second (vs what are they for 10 seconds)?  And what is the initial radius and final radius for those conditions?

Comment: Or maybe make your minimum timeRate 10, 50 or 100 milliseconds, see if that gives you more consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have done. You can adjust the animation by adjusting the time interval given in setTimeout function. http://jsbin.com/oritec/2/edit

```
 function getCircle() {
    var circle = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: 0.6,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 0.6
    };
    return circle;
      }
      function init() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.7833, 5.2167);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      'zoom': 2,
      'center': mapCenter,
       draggable: false,
       disableDefaultUI: true,
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var rad = 0;
    var sop = 1;
    var sw = 1;
    var fillop = 1;     
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(18.7000, 79.1833),
      icon: getCircle(),
      draggable: false
    });

   for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
     {  
       setTimeout(function(){                   
                    animate();
                    rad += 50000;
                    sop -= 0.1;
                    fillop -= 0.1;
                    sw -= 0.1;
                },i* 50);
     }  

  function animate(){
         var circle2 = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: rad, 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.7000, 79.1833),
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: fillop,
      strokeWeight: sw,
      strokeOpacity: sop
    });
     setTimeout(function(){ 
       circle2.setMap(null); },100);
}   
      } 
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```