# Creating event animation on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create an event animation method using **`google.maps.Circle`** on google map.

What I mean by event animation: Say I'm trying to create a small expanding circle animation on the map when someone buys an item from a website. An event is released with the lat, lon and the script should be able to show a small animation of expanding circle at that location.

So far I have been able to **simulate**  1000 animations on every click at random locations using :

```
function animate(map, lat, lon) {
    var counter = 0;
    var arrayObj = new Array();
    var count = 1;
    for (var counter = 0;counter < 10 ; counter++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
          strokeColor:"#160EB3",
          strokeOpacity:0.2,
          strokeWeight:2,
          fillColor:"#160EB3",
          fillOpacity:0.5
        });
        myCity.setRadius((count++ * (21 - map.getZoom()) * 10) * (21 - map.getZoom()) * 2);
        myCity.setMap(map);
        if(arrayObj.length > 0)
            arrayObj[0].setVisible(false);
        arrayObj[0] = myCity;
        if(count == 11)
            arrayObj[0].setVisible(false);
    }, counter * 60);
  }
}
```

Calling the script :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay) {
    for(var k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
        setTimeout(function(){animate(map, overlay.latLng.jb + Math.random() * 3, overlay.latLng.kb + Math.random()* 4)}, k * 1000);
    }
});
```

Problem:

- Animation is not smooth.
- It raises CPU utilization to abnormal levels.
- Unable to make the radius constant on different zoom levels.

Is there any alternative to do the same?

Comment: This [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259140/animating-radius-growth-shrink-of-a-circle-on-google-maps-in-a-given-time) might be helpful

Comment: The comment is too trivial to post as an answer.